# Convert string (nvarchar2) datatype 'timestamp' column to date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, date-conversion

I have an Oracle table column named 'timestamp' with 'nvarchar2' datatype
eg. ('-144041977')

Need to convert the above to any applicable/readable date format.

Any help appreciated / Thanks

Comment: What human readable date do you expect from the value `-144041977` ? perhaps a couple more examples (both the value and the expected date) would also help you get an answer

Comment: It looks like an epoch time, but I don't remember ever seeing a negative one, and it's fairly low. If so that would represent 1965-06-08 20:20:23 UTC - does that sound likely for your data? There are lots of examples of converting from epoch to Oracle dates, if that is what this is. It could be some bespoke representation used by your application though.